# Javascript image gallery : for loop for next and previous button is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an image gallery using JavaScript.

I have all of the images in a folder called 'images' and also have them in an array, so I can loop them.

I have a 'next' button which its purpose is to display the next image, and a 'previous' button to display the previous image. 
However, it's only half working: when I click on next, it just displays to me the second image in the array and won't go through the other ones, and when I click on previous, it just shows me an empty image.

Here is my JS code:

```
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg', 'images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg'];
var index = 0;
document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];

var next = document.getElementById('slider-next');
var previous = document.getElementById('slider-previous');
//NEXT BUTTON

next.addEventListener('click', nextImage);

function nextImage(){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index + 1];
    }
}
//'Previous' button

previous.addEventListener('click', previousImage);

function previousImage(){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index - 1];
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <section class="button">

  <button id="slider-previous"><i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true" class="icon"></i></button>

  <button id="slider-toggle"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" class="icon"></i></button>

  <button id="slider-next"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true" class="icon"></i></button>

  <button id="slider-random"><i class="fa fa-random" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

</section>

<section class="gallery">

  <img id='imgsrc' src="">

</section>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

I appreciate all responses

Comment: can you upload a fiddle?
Also, I don't understand why you use the for loops

Comment: @Roysh yeah i will, in jus a couple seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you use these for loops.

Anyhow, replace these functions with this code.

```
function nextImage() {
    index+=1;
    if (index > images.length - 1) {
     index = 0;
    }

     document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];

}
//'Previous' button

previous.addEventListener('click', previousImage);

function previousImage(){
    index-=1;
    if (index < 0) {
     index = images.length - 1;
    }

     document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment index when calling nextImage and decrement when calling previousImage. Also, I added the if statements to prevent going out of array bounds.

```
function nextImage() {
  if(index < images.length - 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index++];
    }
  }
}

function previousImage() {
  if(index > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index--];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//NEXT BUTTON

next.addEventListener('click', nextImage);

function nextImage(){
    if(index<images.length-1)
    {
        index++;
        document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];
    }

}
//'Previous' button

previous.addEventListener('click', previousImage);

function previousImage(){
    if(index>0)
    {
    index--;
    document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];
    }

}
```